# How To Give Entire Area Behind List Item Inside A DIV A Background Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a side bar with 4 different options, when the selected option is active (Meaning you are on that specific page), I want the entire area behind the li, but inside the DIV, a background color slightly darker than what is already there but don't know how to achieve this. I have tried making the li itself 100% width of the div but it doesn't affect it at all.
Here is the issue:
[image: Here is the issue]
As you can see the li does not reach the start and end width of the sidebar div.

Code Here -

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lakeside Books</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="masterstyle.css">
    <meta name="viewsize" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <nav id="nav">
            <div id="searchbar">
                <form action="http://www.example.com/search.php">
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter Book Title"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a id="firstlink">
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a id="secondlink">
                        Categories
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a id="thirdlink">
                        Bestsellers
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a id="fourthlink">
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{

    background-color: #f1f6f6;
}

#sidebar{
    background-color: #212528;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav{
    margin: 2em 1em;
    color: #888888;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}

#nav li{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}

#searchbar{
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    text-align: right;
}

#searchbar input{
    max-width: 95%;
}
```

Comment: because you are setting a margin for your nav element, if you want your nav element to be 100% width of its container take off the right/left margin

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your #nav.  You need to remove the x-margins:

```
#nav{
    margin: 2em 0;
}
```

You can then do something like this:

```
#nav li:hover
{
    background:#333;
}
```

But you'll also want to fix this:

```
#searchbar{
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5amL4tx5/

Comment: Thanks so much for that, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the #nav rule. If you remove the margins it will fill the entire containing div.

```
#nav{
  margin: 2em 1em;
  color: #888888;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

As for changing the background to make it darker for the active element. I suggest creating an .active class and assigning that on the fly to the active page based off of the url.

Example active class:

```
.active {
  background: c2c2c2;
}
```

Comment: Note that I didn't actually remove the margins in my answer, I'm just cited the code to point out which rule I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here (specifically the 1em for left/right margin):

```
#nav{
    margin: 2em 1em;
}
```

That's going to limit the size of anything within #nav.